# A value of type 'StackLayout' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the Error : **A value of type 'StackLayout' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList**.

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="Contunie" Margin="0" HeightRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#24348b">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Contunie_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Font="20" Margin="0,15,0,0"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White"  
                   FontFamily="{DynamicResource GothamRoundedMedium}" Text="{Translator:Translate SendMessage}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: The shared XAML is valid. Sharing the rest would help.

Comment: I also get the same error. Seems like a bug in Xamarin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. A rebuild will get rid of the problem. If something was actually wrong with your xaml, your page would most likely fail to load.

Answer (score 1):

If a re-build didn't work, restart your visual studio will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after update the Xamarin Forms to 3.2, after downgrade back to 3.1.0.697729, the issue is gone.